# Eclipse CDT, how to make it NOT search for system headers?

Tags: include, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-luna

I'm porting a C project compiled on linux to an arm platform using Eclipse Luna on Ubuntu 16.04

When I switch from CC=gcc to CC=arm-none-eabi in the Makefile I get a lot of missing headers and that's ok, that's what the porting job is about.

What bothers me is that when I CTRL-click on a symbol Eclipse doesn't open the corresponding file for the arm toolchain. For instance if I CTRL-click on `<time.h>` it does NOT open:

```
/media/BUILDS/arm_gcc493/arm-none-eabi/include/time.h
```

but instead it always reverts to its linux system counterpart, in this case

```
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/time.h
```

because that's where *gcc* would look for but I'm compiling with arm-none-eabi-gcc instead!

I don't want Eclipse to do that because debugging gets really confusing. If I have a problem with the header/source I'm actually trying to compile with, I want Eclipse to open me that file and not the default system one. I fiddled with Project Properties and Eclipse Preferences but with no luck.

Even worse, whenever `<sys/socket.h>` is included I get an error because the arm toolchain does not have `socket.h` but if I CTRL-click on it Eclipse takes me to `/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/socket.h`

I dont' want that, if the header needed for compilation is not there, it's just not there. I don't want Eclipse to show me other stuff, how do I do that?

The project was created importing into the workspace "Existing Code as Makefile Project" under C/C++

Thank you very much

EDIT:

I did the proper thing and started from scratch creating a project for the Cross ARM GCC Toolchain (with the proper plug-in). My mistake was creating a "Linux GCC" Project and pretending that Eclipse understood what I was trying to achieve just by launching a different "make" command. If, however, you can't restart from scratch, the accepted solution instructs you on how to fix the situation manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To resolve this situation you need to update the *Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros, etc.* setting to use your custom-prefix GCC.

To make the change:

1. Open Project Properties (Right-click on project and choose *Properties*)
2. In *C/C++ General* -> *Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros, etc.*, choose *Providers* tab
3. Select *CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings*
4. Uncheck *Use global provider shared between projects*
5. Replace `${COMMAND}` with `arm-none-eabi-gcc` or `arm-none-eabi-g++`

Alternatively, you can also edit the same setting at the workspace level to affect all the projects in your workspace. Go to *Window* -> *Preferences* -> *C/C++* -> *Build* -> *Settings* -> *Discovery* tab instead.

Here are some screenshots that may help.

Before:

[image: before]

Project Properties:

[image: project properties]

After:

[image: after]

Comment: Thanks, I think your solution works. However, I did the proper thing and started from scratch creating a project for the Cross ARM GCC Toolchain (with the proper plug-in). My mistake was creating a "Linux GCC" Project and pretending that Eclipse understood what I was trying to achieve just by launching a different "make" command

Comment: Glad you found a solution. It would be great if you wrote up yours as the solution and accepted the answer as the best answer is probably what you actually did! That said, more or less the Cross ARM GCC Toolchain will just have done automatically what I did manually. It may do some other things too, but most of them are related to using Managed projects (Where Eclipse CDT creates the Makefile for you).

Comment: Exactly ;) Your solution will come in handy to those who can't restart from scratch like I did and have to sanitize the situation manually